# List of RISCV architectures supported for spike?

Tags: riscv

What are the legal fields to enter for the RISCV spike command option "--isa=".  I quickly searched the spike source code and only found the DEFAULT_ISA define.

Answer (score 2):

The code of spike is pretty nice to read and not very complicated. In the main procedure the argument for the `isa`-option is stored in the variable `isa`. This is passed to the constructor of `sim_t`, from there to the constructor of `processor_t` and there it is parsed in the function [`parse_isa_string`](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim/blob/9e012462f53113dc9ed00d7fbb89aeafeb9b89e9/riscv/processor.cc#L57).

If the string for `isa` is empty the extensions `imafdc` are enabled and the processor is in 64 bit mode. A non-empty string can just be the letter code of the extensions, e.g. `imac`, or it can have the prefix `rv` with an optional register width of the processor, e.g. `rv32gc`.

Comment: OK I am reviewing the code area you mention.  Now I am wondering how spike handles any conflicts between architecture selection and the input code.  Will spike stop execution or warn if say 64 bit code is input to a 32 bit ISA selection?  e.g. "--isa=rv32g"?  I realize that I should test this myself but I am not confident with my gcc build options.